# Certain words supposedly in Russian that I can't verify!

Tags: значения, одним-словом

My late mother-in-law's story of her captivity in the Soviet Union as a German civilian forced laborer after WW2 contains a number of words which are apparently Russian, but for which I cannot find any confirmation (some of them I can find, but these others are giving me trouble).  The original text is a transcription in German from an audio recording.

- A word commanding "to stop".  In her description she gives "Stoy!" as a command from the Russian soldier who captured her.  Bing Translater says "stop!" is "стоп!" which of course transliterates to "stop!"  Is there some word, "stoy", which answers to what she remembers hearing?
- A word that seems to sound like "yest", used in demanding one to show personal documents.  This word in the exchange that she describes sounds like "yest", and occurs with the word in German and Russian for "document" ("документы" or "Dokumente")
- A word for an article of winter clothing, a quilted jacket.  The word she uses is "kupeikas", which I cannot find anywhere.  In her tale, the clothing item is using in connection with the felt boots, valenki or Валенки.

Comment: "kupeikas" Maybe you just mishear it and it is in fact "Фуфайка"? The way it is pronounced in Russian is with the stress on "-фай-" and often rather inarticulate "Фу-", so it not so easy to recognize it for a non-native speaker who hasn't heard it before.

Comment: I don't have the audio, just the transcription that my sister-in-law made.  I am assuming that Фуфайка is the term that was actually used.

Comment: The 1st word is still part of standard formalized phrases that sentries are mandated to use: "Стой! Кто идёт?" and "Стой! Стрелять буду!" - kind of "Stop! Who are you going here?" and "Stop! I will resort to shooting you!". There would be no third phrase but two shots into the air as last warnings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, let me try.

1. "Стой!" or "стоять!" (stoy or, in infinitive, stoyat') is a phrase which indeed is used like English "freeze!" or "stay where you are". In fact, "стой" and "stay" share same origin on PIE level.
2. Depends on context. It can be "есть" (yest) with the meaning "there is/there are" (literally, "is"). "Do you have any documents?" - "У вас есть с собой какие-то документы?" -  "Есть". On the other hand, "есть" is a standard confirmation phrase in Russian Army. It is sort of English "Sir, yes sir".
3. Hm, this is indeed quite weird. You see, there is indeed such word "купейке" (koopeyke), it is a national fur clothing of [Khakas people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khakas_people). I can easily imagine this word respelled as "купейка", such phonetic transformation is typical to Russian. I can also admit the probability of using this word in a wider context, but personally I've never heard of such. Still, may be you are actually searching for some other word.

Comment: Avm is right: the guard would likely say just "Документы есть?" instead of long polite phrases.

Comment: Weird story. And the guard would take the answer for granted? That way any spy or burglar would say he's got papers. It should be "Предъявите пропуск/документы" instead.

Answer (score 11):

1. *Stoy* (стой) is imperative for *stoyat'* "to stand", and can be used as a command to stand still.
2. *Dokumenty yest'?* (Документы есть?) translates to "Have you got you papers?".
3. The word in question may be *fufayka* (фуфайка), which used to be a synonym for *vatnik* (ватник), or quilted jacket.

Comment: a-ha-ha, фуфайка, of course, very nice. as for other parts of answer. Please, next time try not to repeat the answers already provided.

Comment: Here in Ukraine people often say "кухвайка" instead of "фуфайка".

Comment: Куфайка is also used in Ukraine (хв is just a "variation" of ф). Даль also has [куфайка](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/260766) entry. [Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0) notes that куфайка is used in Poland as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the word for winter cloth article might be шубейка (shubeika). The word derive from shuba, winter fur coat (шуба). 
Шубейка is rather pitiful looking, maybe super old and worn out, maybe cheap and thin, does not give much protection from cold weather.

In the situation your mother-in-law is talking about, many people would wear such clothes.

It is just my guess, of course I might be wrong.

Comment: Вряд ли пленным немцам давали "шубейки". Их одежда скорее была похожа на одежду заключенных, чем обычных гражданских.

Comment: если у местного правительства в 1945 были ресурсы, чтобы делать разную одежду для разных лиц. Что не факт.